# How can I force parsley.js to revalidate the input when it is filled with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

How can I force parsley.js to revalidate the input when it is filled with autocomplete?
There is nothing about it in documentation:
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, autocomplete, pasting, etc., should all trigger the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input), which is what Parsley is listening for so it should work out of the box.

Comment: If that's not the case in your browser (assuming latest version), let me know which + OS so I can file a bug.

Comment: It end up that parsley is validating autofill but I cannot override that yellow color and show my success check mark   [autofill without checkmark][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgGRT.png

Comment: If so, then clearly this has nothing to do with parsley and your original question has been answered.